# Input e Output - Definição

Tags: haskell

Qual é a definição das seguintes funções predefenidas do `System.Random ::`

a) `randomRIO :: (Int,Int)-> IO Int`

b) `putChar :: Char -> IO ()`

Comment: ``putChar`` não é definida junto com ``randomRIO``, mas em ``System.IO``. Você pode ver a definição de ambas no Hackage. ``randomRIO``: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRIO. ``putChar``: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:putChar.